# How do I eliminate "labels" from the Gmail app on Android?

Tags: gmail

The Gmail on my tablet has a bunch of old "labels" from past email traffic, and I wish to remove/delete those labels.

None of the old labels have any documents in them (they are empty), but they are still shown on the left side of the Gmail screen. They are listed under the headings: "Recent Labels" and "All Labels"

By the way, I did access another screen that has the following listings:

- delete labels
- remove labels
- label:Junk-E-mail-FRIENDS
- cancel labels
- discard labels
- labels
- remove account
- remove account withdrawal
- create labels

I tried all the above commands to eliminate the labels appearing, but with no luck.

The message I get is ...

> Whoops! We didn't find anything for "xxxx labels"

How do I remove these old label listings from appearing on my screen?

Answer (score 2):

From app help, search for *Remove Labels*

On a computer, open Gmail. You can't edit labels from the Gmail app.

- On the left side of the page, hover your cursor over your label's name.
- Click the Down arrow.
- Click Remove label

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand that I had to use my notebook to open up Gmail on the Nexus Tablet, and edit the label listings.

Answer (score 1):

If you open Gmail in a web browser, at the very bottom of the page it says mobile, older version, desktop; choose desktop. Now you can add, edit, or delete labels and folders from your mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a mere refresh does not work. You will have to remove the label from desktop Gmail. Any removal of label will only be reflected in your Android Gmail app once you clear the data.

1. Make necessary changes from desktop to your labels.
2. Go to phone settings - Applications - Gmail - Storage - Clear data (+ cache)

This will work!

Answer (score 0):

It's true you can't customize your labels from within the Gmail app in Android, but you don't need to physically do it from a notebook or desktop, you can still do it right from your Android phone by using Gmail through your web browser ⁠᎓

- Use the Google search bar on your phone to search for "gmail"
- Tap the first result  (" ⁠Gmail - Google ⁠")
- If asked whether to open the web version or use the Gmail app, choose
  the web version, and you'll be looking at the familiar contents of
  your Gmail Inbox, only on the web via your browser  ( ⁠see *footnote* ⁠)
- Tap the '**≡**' symbol, top left
- Scroll to the bottom to where, in very small print, it says **View
  Gmail in ⁠᎓**  and tap the blue **Desktop** link

Now you're looking at your Gmail Inbox exactly as you would see it on your desktop or notebook computer, so from here you proceed just as you would if that's what you were using. In this case ⁠᎓

- At the bottom of the left column, tap the blue **Edit labels** link

You're shown *only* the labels you're allowed to customize, each one with its own set of  **[ ⁠Rename ⁠]** ⁠/ **[ ⁠Remove ⁠]** buttons ⁠… proceed accordingly  ( ⁠and carefully ⁠! ⁠).

---

*If at this point you're **not** given the choice of opening the web version and the Gmail app opens automatically, it's because you need to clear the **Set as default** flag for the Gmail app in your phone's settings. The procedure for this will vary a bit depending on phone model, but on the Samsung Galaxy S8+, it's  **[ ⁠Settings ▸ Apps ▸ Gmail ▸ Set as default ▸ Clear defaults ⁠]**,  so 5 taps.*